# Making window size the same as background image size in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF so bear with me. I have set the background image of my window using an ImageBrush and now I want my window's size to be exactly the size of the background image. The obvious solution to this is to simply set the width/height property manually with the pixel measurements of my background image, but this seems too naive. What is the best way to do this? Here is my XAML so far:

```
<Window x:Class="FruitFactory.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Fruit Factory" Height="576" WindowStyle="None" DataContext="{Binding}" ResizeMode="NoResize" Width="834">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/FruitFactory;component/Graphics/FruitFactoryBackground.png"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,27,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind Width and Height to PixelWidth and PixelHeight of the ImageSource for ImageBrush like this

**Update**

Realized my previous solution didn't work because ImageSource didn't have PixelWidth/PixelHeight since it wasn't a BitmapImage. I had to use a BitmapImage resource instead but then the bindings didn't work if I didn't declare the Resource before the bindings (bug anyone?)

```
<Window x:Class="WindowSameSizeAsBackground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Fruit Factory"
        WindowStyle="None"
        DataContext="{Binding}"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="backgroundBrush"
                     UriSource="/FruitFactory;component/Graphics/FruitFactoryBackground.png"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Width>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource backgroundBrush}" Path="PixelWidth"/>
    </Window.Width>
    <Window.Height>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource backgroundBrush}" Path="PixelHeight"/>
    </Window.Height>
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush"
                    ImageSource="{StaticResource backgroundBrush}"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,27,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,179,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This seems to almost work. Are the Width/Height attributes for Window measured in Pixels? The size is close, but not perfect, and I still see some stretching of the background image. I realize WPF is resolution independent but I was hoping for a way to get my background image measured in pixels exactly.

Comment: @Bob: Updated my answer, this solution will work better. Unfortunately it became a little less straight forward.. The BitmapImage can be placed in App.xaml as a cleaner solution

Comment: @Meleak: That is exactly the solution i had in mind: Binding to PixelWidth/PixelHeight, didn't get it work though; quite weird how the components need to be declared...

Comment: @Meleak: Your updated solution works perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind your background will only look any good on the default DPI. With a higher DPI the background image will stretch out and look ugly. If you give a higher-res image and let it scale down when at low-DPI, it should look good in all modes.

Comment: @H.B.: I had to try a few times to get it working as well. And the order they (apparently) need to be declared in is very weird indeed, and I really don't understand it

Answer (score 1):

ImageBrush isn't best solution for such requirements, because it hasn't Width/Height properties and does not present in VisualTree (it's just a tool for rendering).

Layers will help you:

```
<Window>
    <Grid >
        <Image Stretch="Fill" 
               Source="***some uri***"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="40" 
                    Margin="20"
                    Content="Ololo"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
<Window>
```